# How to create a statement for subtract a date omitting weekends and holidays in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to make a query where from a final date specific days are subtracted, omitting weekends (Saturday and Sunday) and holidays,
Once the operation is done, it proceeds to display the date resulting from that operation, for example:

**(3/1/2023 - 7) = 2/20/2023**

On March 3, 7 days are subtracted, if I apply that statement it should show 2/23/2023 but since within that operation it went through Saturday and Sunday, it must omit them and continue subtracting as long as the days are between
Monday to Friday.
I've a table where I already have the festive dates, I would only check if there is also a festive date, it is omitted and continues subtracting.

Is possible to create that statement?

Comment: In Oracle I'd suggest to write a PL/SQL function for this. The programming language makes it possible to write a simple loop in which you check whether to count a day or not. It is possible in SQL, but more complicated (I'd probably write a recursive query there to mimic a loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; it uses holidays table (which you have) and a function (which creates a calendar, marks weekends and holidays and skips them in a loop).

Holidays:

```
SQL> select * from holidays order by datum;

DATUM
----------
01.11.2022
25.12.2022
26.12.2022
01.01.2023
06.01.2023
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_result
  2    (par_datum in date, par_number_of_days in number)
  3    return date
  4  is
  5    retval date   := par_datum;
  6    i      number := 0;
  7  begin
  8    for cur_r in
  9      -- calendar
 10      (with
 11       temp (datum) as
 12        (select par_datum - level + 1
 13         from dual
 14         connect by level <= par_number_of_days + 20
 15        )
 16        -- mark weekends and holidays
 17        select t.datum,
 18            case when to_char(t.datum, 'dy') in ('sat', 'sun') then 1 else 0 end cb_weekend,
 19            case when t.datum = h.datum then 1 else 0 end cb_holiday
 20          from temp t left join holidays h on h.datum = t.datum
 21          order by t.datum desc
 22      ) loop
 23        retval := cur_r.datum;
 24        -- skip weekends and holidays
 25        i := i + case when cur_r.cb_weekend = 1 or cur_r.cb_holiday = 1 then 0 else 1 end;
 26        exit when i > par_number_of_days;
 27    end loop;
 28    return retval;
 29  end;
 30  /

Function created.
```

Calendar (January 2023; names are in Croatian, but disregard that. Weekends and holidays are marked in different color. Today's date is 20.01.2023 (dd.mm.yyyy)):

[image]

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_result(date '2023-01-20', 10) from dual;

F_RESULT(D
----------
05.01.2023

SQL> select f_result(date '2023-01-10', 7) from dual;

F_RESULT(D
----------
29.12.2022

SQL>
```

---

If you'd want to move *forward*, slightly change function code:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_result
  2    (par_datum in date, par_number_of_days in number)
  3    return date
  4  is
  5    retval date   := par_datum;
  6    i      number := 0;
  7  begin
  8    for cur_r in
  9      -- calendar
 10      (with
 11       temp (datum) as
 12        (select par_datum + level - 1
 13         from dual
 14         connect by level <= par_number_of_days + 20
 15        )
 16        -- mark weekends and holidays
 17        select t.datum,
 18            case when to_char(t.datum, 'dy') in ('sat', 'sun') then 1 else 0 end cb_weekend,
 19            case when t.datum = h.datum then 1 else 0 end cb_holiday
 20          from temp t left join holidays h on h.datum = t.datum
 21          order by t.datum
 22      ) loop
 23        retval := cur_r.datum;
 24        -- skip weekends and holidays
 25        i := i + case when cur_r.cb_weekend = 1 or cur_r.cb_holiday = 1 then 0 else 1 end;
 26        exit when i > par_number_of_days;
 27    end loop;
 28    return retval;
 29  end;
 30  /

Function created.
```

For example:

```
SQL> select f_result(date '2022-12-30', 1) res_1,
  2         f_result(date '2023-01-04', 7) res_2,
  3         f_result(date '2023-03-03', 7) res_3,
  4         f_result(date '2023-03-01', 7) res_4
  5  from dual;

RES_1      RES_2      RES_3      RES_4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
02.01.2023 16.01.2023 14.03.2023 10.03.2023

SQL>
```

Specifically, `RES_3` you mentioned in comment (as 3rd January 2023 + 7 days) is:

```
03.01.2023 + 7 = 
  day 1: 04.01.
  day 2: 05.01.
  skip   06.01. (holiday), 07.01. and 08.01. (weekend)
  day 3: 09.01.
  day 4: 10.01.
  day 5: 11.01.
  day 6: 12.01.
  day 7: 13.01.  --> RES_3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great! One more question, how would it be if it were the opposite? That is, instead of counting backwards, count forwards?

Comment: You're welcome. To move forward, you'd modify function code - have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: I used the code to go ahead but it doesn't work correctly if I put the example date it should be like this
  (3/1/2023 + 7) = 3/10/2023 , but it gives me the following (3/1/2023 + 7) = 3/16/2023

Comment: Then you did something wrong. See another edit, which show explicitly what happens for 3rd of January 2023 + 7 days (result is 13.01.2023, as it should be).

Comment: I see, but the date that I comment is 3rd March 2023 MM/DD/YYYY format and when I run the function it shows 3/16/2023 (16 th March 2023)

Comment: No, for 3rd of March (+ 7 days) result is 14th of March 2023. Did you check your **holidays** table? I don't have any in **my** holidays table (see sample data I posted).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean day 3 but day 1, that is, 3/1/2023 + 7
  
  2/3/2023 = 1
  3/3/2023 = 1
  3/4/2023 = Saturday (skip)
  3/5/2023 = Sun (Skip)
  3/6/2023 = 1
  3/7/2023 = 1
  3/8/2023 = 1
  3/9/2023 = 1
  03/10/2023 = 1 This is the date, ending 7 days count

Comment: That is correct. 1st of March 2023 + 7 days = 10th of March 2023. That's what function returns (see last example in my answer, RES_4).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I hadn't noticed that I didn't remove a + in the function, so it gave me different dates.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad you found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  v_result_date date := to_date('03/01/2023','mm/dd/yyyy');
  v_days number := 7;
begin 
 while v_days > 0
  loop

    if to_char(v_result_date,'dy') not in ('sat','sun')
    then
      v_days := v_days - 1;
    end if;   
    v_result_date := v_result_date - 1;

  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result_date);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with SQL using model clause. You could try this.
SAMPLE data for holydays and your DATE 2023-03-01 with 7 days backward count taking care of weekends and holydays:

```sql
WITH
    holydays (A_DATE) AS
        (
            Select DATE '2023-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-01-06' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-04-09' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-04-10' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-06-08' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-06-22' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-08-05' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-08-15' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-11-01' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-11-18' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-12-25' From Dual Union All
            Select DATE '2023-12-26' From Dual 
        ),
    test_period AS
        (
          Select To_Date('2023-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "REF_DATE", 7 "NUM_OF_DAYS" From Dual 
        ),
```

Now, using Oracle SQL MODEL Clause, we could createCTE returning a dataset that will have a kind of reversed set of dates excluding weekend and holyday days.

```sql
  days AS
    (   SELECT    IDX, REF_DATE, ROWNUM - 1 "RN", DAY_OF_WEEK, NUM_OF_DAYS 
        FROM   (  Select      IDX, REF_DATE, NUM_OF_DAYS, 
                              CASE WHEN Nvl(To_Char(A_DATE), 'N') = 'N' And
                                        Case When SubStr(To_Char(REF_DATE, 'Day'), 1, 3) IN('Sat', 'Sun') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End = 'N'
                                    THEN 1
                              END "DAYS_PAST",
                              To_Char(REF_DATE, 'Day') "DAY_OF_WEEK",
                              A_DATE,
                              Nvl(To_Char(A_DATE), 'N')  "IS_HOLYDAY",
                              Case When SubStr(To_Char(REF_DATE, 'Day'), 1, 3) IN('Sat', 'Sun') Then 'Y' Else 'N' End "IS_WEEKEND"
                  From    (   Select  REF_DATE, NUM_OF_DAYS  From test_period   ) p
                  Left Join   holydays h ON(h.A_DATE = REF_DATE)
                        MODEL
                            Dimension By        (0 as IDX)
                            Measures              (REF_DATE, NUM_OF_DAYS, A_DATE, 0 AS DAYS_PAST)
                              RULES     ITERATE(100)   -- NUMBER OF ITERATIONS SHOULD BE BIGGER TO COVER SKIPPED DAYS
                                  (
                                    REF_DATE[ITERATION_NUMBER] = REF_DATE[0] - ITERATION_NUMBER,
                                    NUM_OF_DAYS[ITERATION_NUMBER] = NUM_OF_DAYS[0]
                                  )
                  Order by REF_DATE DESC
              )
        WHERE DAYS_PAST Is Not Null And ROWNUM <= NUM_OF_DAYS + 1
    )

  R e s u l t :
       IDX REF_DATE          RN DAY_OF_WEEK NUM_OF_DAYS
---------- --------- ---------- ----------- -----------
         0 01-MAR-23          0 Wednesday             7 
         1 28-FEB-23          1 Tuesday               7 
         2 27-FEB-23          2 Monday                7 
         5 24-FEB-23          3 Friday                7 
         6 23-FEB-23          4 Thursday              7 
         7 22-FEB-23          5 Wednesday             7 
         8 21-FEB-23          6 Tuesday               7 
         9 20-FEB-23          7 Monday                7
```

Now just select the date you want - the 7th date backwards counting just working days.

```sql
SELECT  REF_DATE "TARGET_DATE"
FROM    days
WHERE   RN = NUM_OF_DAYS

7 days from 2023-03-01
TARGET_DATE
-----------
20-FEB-23
```